# How do I resolve FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in Google Colab shutil.copy

Tags: python, directory, path, google-colaboratory, shutil

I have my Google Drive mounted in Colab and am able to import/upload files from those locations. However, when I try to execute the code below in Colab I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

```
flooding_folder = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Learning/LR_PyTprch_API_Ray_Tune/input/images/flooding/'
no_flooding_folder = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Learning/LR_PyTorch_API_Ray_Tune/input/images/no_flooding/'

for file in s1_file_list:
  for directory in os.listdir(source_dir_1):
    src_file = os.path.join(source_dir_1,directory,file)
    if file[:-7] in labels_flood:
      shutil.copyfile(src_file, flooding_folder)
    else:
      shutil.copyfile(src_file, no_flooding_folder)
```

Running the above chunk results in the following:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-2d8df0a28b1c> in <module>
      3     src_file = os.path.join(source_dir_1,directory,file)
      4     if file[:-7] in labels_flood:
----> 5       shutil.copyfile(src_file, flooding_folder)
      6     else:
      7       shutil.copyfile(src_file, no_flooding_folder)

/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    119     else:
    120         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
--> 121             with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    122                 copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
    123     return dst

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Learning/LR_PyTprch_API_Ray_Tune/input/images/flooding/'
```

When I try `os.chdir(flooding)`, I get the same error despite Drive being mounted. Calling `os.listdir(os.getcwd())` returns `['.config', 'drive', 'sample_data']` and running `!ls` in the cell returns `drive  sample_data`. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Try adding an `os.makedirs(flooding_folder, exist_ok=True)` before  your loop.

Comment: Thanks. Upon trying that, I get this error: ```IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Learning/LR_PyTprch_API_Ray_Tune/input/images/flooding/'```.

Comment: It's because you are using `shutil.copyfile`, which expects both source and destination to be file paths. Either do `shutil.copy2`, or use `os.path.join(flooding_folder, file)` as the destination inside copyfile.